# React attempted import error - when using index.js

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a problem importing some components in my React app:

`src/styled/ProjectEntity/index.js`:

```
export { ProjectEntity } from "./ProjectEntity";
export { ProjectEntityName } from "./ProjectEntityName";
export { ProjectEntityInfo } from "./ProjectEntityInfo";
```

`src/containers/Project/Project/styles.tsx`:

```
import { ProjectEntity } from "styled/ProjectEntity";
```

The error:

```sh
Compiling...
Failed to compile.

./src/styled/ProjectEntity/index.js
Attempted import error: 'ProjectEntity' is not exported from './ProjectEntity'.
```

The thing is, when I do the import like this:

```
import ProjectEntity from "styled/ProjectEntity/ProjectEntity";
```

it works (no braces, cuz it's a default export from `ProjectEntity.tsx`)

Is there something I am doing wrong?

P.S Note that I use `index.js` as an export aggregator all over my project in many directiories and it works splendidly.

Comment: if its the default export and they live in the same folder 

```import ProjectEntity from "./ProjectEntity"``` 

should work?

btw, do you mean import instead of export in the first code section?

Comment: Nope, I mean to export, this is how I do it in many other places and it works

Comment: Ah, misread the question sorry. I am not sure if one module can have multiple export member statements. Does it work when you import them one by one and then export like this?

`export { ProjectEntity, ProjectEntityName, ProjectEntityInfo }`

Comment: Done exactly as you suggested, it doesn't work. And this is really strange because I have multiple exports like this, for example: `export { Dictionary } from "./generic";
export {
  RowClickConfig,
  TableColumnInterface,
  TableRowInterface,
} from "./paginatedTable";
export { ProjectData } from "./project";
export { TaskData } from "./task";
export { defaultUserContext, UserContext } from "./userContext";
export { UserData } from "./userData";` (I know it looks bad in comment) - but it works

Comment: Just tried it myself and seems it doesn't work with default exports. It worked for me when i changed the ProjectEntity file to export a member, like

`export const ProjectEntity = () => {}`

Comment: then importing like 

`import { ProjectEntity } from './ProjectEntity'`

in the index worked correctly

Comment: Hi, not familiar with the export ... from ... syntax, but if you claim it works I'll take your word for it. Assuming that it works, your problem seems to be in the import statement in styles.tsx. I would try it like this:  import { ProjectEntity } from "../styled/ProjectEntity"; since both files exists in sibling folders of the same parent, the ../ syntax tells the importer to look in the current folder's parent (which is the /src folder).

Comment: @tutiplain I tried relative imports - no luck. @ilwcss, my `ProjectEntity.tsx` has this at the end: `export default ProjectEntity;`. And I use the default export because: `Prefer default export. eslint(import/prefer-default-export)`

Comment: Okay, I just realized that those imports don't work in my project. VS Code auto importer actually doesn't use those `index.js` files, it forces the use of something like `ProjectEntity/ProjectEntity`, so I am importing directly from the file. However, one trick has worked for me here: `export { default as ProjectEntity } from "./ProjectEntity";` - I did that in `index.js` and it works. Dunno if that's a good practice though